# def command not found in jenkinsfile or pipeliene

Tags: jenkins

stage('docker commands'){
steps{
sh '''
var readProp = readProperties file: "ripropsfile.properties"
echo """ The target value is ${readProp['GIT_SHA_TARGET']} """
echo """ The target value is ${readProp['GIT_SHA_SHORT']} """
'''
}
}

- def readProp = readProperties file: ripropsfile.properties
  19:43:39  /home/opc/workspace/docthraki/RI_Pipeline_job_tmp/durable-66a62c4b/script.sh: line 2: def: command not found

19:43:40  ERROR: script returned exit code 127
19:43:40  Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sh` interpretator to execute Jenkins DSL. Also, replace `var` with `def`:

```
stage('docker commands'){ 
    steps{ 
        def readProp = readProperties file: "ripropsfile.properties"
        echo "The target value is ${readProp['GIT_SHA_TARGET']}"
        echo "The target value is ${readProp['GIT_SHA_SHORT']}"
    }
}
```

P.S. I am not very good in declarative syntax. I prefer Groovy. Use as a reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text